# Multiple $or inside $and query in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to do OR statements after an AND statement. I want to do something like ...WHERE gender = 'female' AND (extract(dow from start) = 2 OR extract(dow from start) = 3)

```
let userWhereQuery = {}
let appointmentWhereQuery = {}

        if (gender != 'none') {
            userWhereQuery['$and'] = sequelize.literal(`lower(gender) = '${gender.toLowerCase()}'`)
        }

        if (days != '') {
            let daysOr = []
            for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
                let dayOr = {
                   ['$or']: sequelize.literal(`extract(dow from start) = ${days[i]}`)
                }
                daysOr.push(dayOr)
            }

            appointmentWhereQuery['$and'] = daysOr
        }
```

The error I get

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid value { '$or':
   Literal {
     val: 'extract(dow from "therapistAppointments"."start") = 1' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because it's not recognising the operator alias. 
Here's an example to give you an idea:

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const operatorsAliases = {
  $and: Op.and,
  $or: Op.or,
  $eq: Op.eq
};
```

And to use:

```
someMethod() => {
  var whereObj = {
          where: {
              gender: 'female',
              [Op.and]: [
                { days: {[Op.eq]: 2 }},
                { days: {[Op.eq]: 3 }}
              ]
          }
  };
  return whereObj;
}
```